# decltype was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, decltype

I am trying to make a program that reads strings and tells me how many punctuation marks are in it. However, when I try to compile it, it gives
the error, "'decltype' was not declared in this scope'. I have just started
c++ in the last month and am new to its concepts.

I'm using Dev C++ 5.11 as the IDE for the code. The code is from the book
c++ Primer fifth edition on page 92

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s("Hello World!!!");
    decltype(s.size() punct_cnt = 0;

    // count the number of punctuation characters in s
    for (auto c : s) // for every char in s
        if (ispunct(c)) // if the character is punctuation
            ++punct_cnt;
    cout << punct_cnt << " punctuation characters in " << s << endl;
}

I expect it to give the output 3, but it gives the error message, "'decltype' was not declared in this scope'.
```

Comment: What is that insane formatting? You missed one bracket: `decltype(s.size()) punct_cnt = 0;` Is that your issue?

Comment: Why are you using DevC++ at all? Simply, don't.

Comment: Works fine on IDEOne:  https://ideone.com/iXUwh2

Comment: what would be the best IDE for c++?

Comment: The formatting got a little messed up when I put it in stack overflow and I didn't feel the need to fix it, sorry about that.

Comment: Don't apologise for it, fix it! You're asking for our free time to help you fix your problem, so make your code look nice for us at least.

Comment: @gradys. I'm fond of CLion, but it requires a license (free for students) and is a bit heavy. Among the free ones, I encourage you to try a few to see what you like.

Comment: IMO, at this level, people should learn `int punct_cnt`. Then size_t. Then, maybe, decl_type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

decltype was only introduced in C++11, and presumably DevC++ is not instructing the compiler to use c++11 mode. In your compiler options, instruct DevC++ to pass the following command-line flag:

```
-std=c++11
```